# Traverse nested maps / objects from keys in an array

Tags: javascript, json

I think a code sample is going to work a lot better than my vocabulary:

```
var keys = ['folder','name'];

var data = { folder: { name: 'Special Folder' } };
```

Given the two vars above, I'm looking for a way to dynamically use the array as a way to look up the object keys (sort of like a "path"). So I need to programmatically produce the following:

```
data['folder']['name'] // that would give me 'Special Folder'
```

Hopefully this makes sense, I just can't quite put all the pieces together.

TIA

Comment: Iterate through the array, looking up the value in the "current" map, starting with the top and carrying the next on ;)

Comment: Not sure this question really belongs here, there's not much to this: http://jsfiddle.net/5ftkcbpe/

Comment: @Hey I'm not sure why this didn't click. I've done this very thing more than couple times in the past, but tonight I just couldn't put it into code for some reason.  Thanks

Comment: @rpaskett no problem... this one won't throw anything if it can't resolve, it'll just return undefined. Change `(target || {})` to `target` if you want it to throw an error for a set of keys it can't resolve.

Comment: Actually `reduce` would make more sense: http://jsfiddle.net/5ftkcbpe/1/

Answer (score 1):

```js
var keys = ['folder','name'];
var data = { folder: { name: 'Special Folder' } };
for(var i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
    data = data[keys[i]];
}
alert(data)
```